# ListView does not update immediately after I add a new item to the ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am learning Xamarin.Forms and I have created a new project with Visual Studio 2019, using the Master-Detail project template. I am using UWP (as I want to make a Windows 10 app).

Why does the list view not show up immediately after I add the new item?
Is this caused by slowness in the event/message passing, or is there an animation that is slowing it down on purpose?

In this sample, everything is happening in a local `ObservableCollection`, and there are only a few items in it, so I expect it to be able to display the change immediately.

Example:

[image: Shows adding an item to an ObservableCollection bound to a ListView]

The code is generated by Visual Studio, I can provide it, but I haven't really made any change.

EDIT:
Since I suspect this is related to the events generated by the ObservableCollection and the bindings in the ListView, I tried the following change, which worked:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
{
    var newItem = item as Item;
    Items.Add(newItem);
    await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
});
```

To:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
{
    var newItem = item as Item;
    var tmp = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    foreach (var i in Items)
    {
        tmp.Add(i);
    }
    tmp.Add(newItem);
    Items = tmp;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
    await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
});
```

Of course, this is inefficient and not ideal but might help someone else figure out what is going on in the original version.
Behaviour after the change:

[image: ListView loading immediately after the change]

Comment: I don't see the problem, it's there, right?

Comment: I would like it to show up as quick as possible, without going through a "white fade" phase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP the views for the navigation back stack are not kept in memory to conserve it, so when you navigate to another page and back, the previous page is reconstructed. In this case however, the reason why it "fades" in is animation, that is built into the default `NavigationPageRenderer` in UWP.

The animation is occurring [here in the code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e6fb094aab97d91ba411fcafdbc4a75ff18be196/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/NavigationPageRenderer.cs#L481), it should be possible to disable the animation by setting the `isAnimated` flag to `false` on the right place, but I don't have my dev device with me right now so I can't test it.

### Update

It seems that this is really a problem with the UWP implementation of either `ListView` or `MasterDetailPage`.

### Workaround

Adding a small delay to the message handler subscription fixes the issue:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NewItemPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    var newItem = item as Item;
    Items.Add(newItem);
    await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);
});
```

I have reported the problem on GitHub as [an issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8695).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't think that is the case, because if I press Cancel rather than Save, the page with the ListView and all the items appear immediately

Comment: You are right, looking at the code that is probably not the case. I will check on my dev machine and try to reproduce it

Comment: I have edited my initial question with an experiment that I did: replacing the whole ObservableCollection with a new one, and raising a `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items))` event. It appears it has worked, but I don't really want to create a copy of the collection every time

Comment: I have updated my answer with a "workaround", but the problem is definitely in the XF implementation, I have reported it at https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8695

Comment: Thank you Martin, I am going to accept this as the answer, since you confirmed it's a bug and provided a workaround.